# Any disadvantages to bit flags in database columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, database-design

Consider the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user_roles(
    pkey         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    bit_id       BIGINT NOT NULL,
    name         VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO user_roles (bit_id,name) VALUES (1,'public');
INSERT INTO user_roles (bit_id,name) VALUES (2,'restricted');
INSERT INTO user_roles (bit_id,name) VALUES (4,'confidential');
INSERT INTO user_roles (bit_id,name) VALUES (8,'secret');

CREATE TABLE news(
    pkey          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title         VARCHAR(256),
    company_fk    INTEGER REFERENCES compaines(pkey), -- updated since asking the question
    body          VARCHAR(512),
    read_roles    BIGINT -- bit flag 
);
```

read_roles is a bit flags that specifies some combination of roles that can read news items. So if I am inserting a news item that can be read by restricted and confidential I would set read_roles to have a value of `2 | 4` or 6 and when I want to get back the news posts that a particular user can see I can use a query like.

```
select * from news WHERE company_fk=2 AND (read_roles | 2 != 0) OR  (read_roles | 4 != 0) ; 
select * from news WHERE company_fk=2 AND read_roles = 6;
```

What are disadvantages of using bit flags in database columns in general? I am assuming the answer to this question might be database specific so I am interested in learning about disadvantages with specific databases.

I am using Postgres 9.1 for my application.

**UPDATE** I got the bit about the database not being to use an index for bit operations which would require a full table scan which would suck for performance. So I have updated the question to reflect my situation more closely, each row in the database belongs to a specific company so all the queries will have WHERE clause that include a company_fk which will have an index on it.

**UPDATE** I only have 6 roles right now, possible more in the future.

**UPDATE** roles are not mutually exclusive and they inherit from each other, for example, restricted inherits all the permissions assigned to public.

Comment: The first disadvantages that come to mind are maintainability and readability. You can't see what somebody's roles are by looking at raw data; you *have* to write a special query to see that (maybe these issues are solved by defining a view where the roles are extrapolated into their own columns).

Comment: How many different roles would you serve with this?

Comment: If you're using Postgres why is this also tagged Oracle and SQL Server?

Comment: The question is tagged with oracle and sql server because I am want to understand the general answers and the database specific ones. Understanding how different db's handle the same issue is very useful to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only have a handful of roles, you don't even save any **storage** space in **PostgreSQL**. An [`integer`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) column uses 4 bytes, a [`bigint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) 8 bytes. Both may require alignment padding:

- [Making sense of Postgres row sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570613/making-sense-of-postgres-row-sizes/13570853#13570853)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)

A [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html) column uses 1 byte. Effectively, you can fit four or more boolean columns for one `integer` column, eight or more for a `bigint`.

Also take into account that `NULL` values only use one bit ([simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383198/939860)) in the [NULL bitmap](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html).

Individual columns are easier to read and **index**. Others have commented on that already.

You could still utilize [indexes on expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) or [partial indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) to circumvent problems with indexes ("non-sargable"). Generalized statements like:

> database cannot use indexes on a query like this

or

> These conditions are non-SARGable!

are *not entirely true* - maybe for some others RDBMS lacking these features.
But why circumvent when you can avoid the problem altogether?

As you have clarified, we are talking about 6 distinct types (maybe more). Go with individual `boolean` columns. You'll probably even save space compared to one `bigint`. Space requirement seems immaterial in this case.

---

**If** these flags were *mutually exclusive*, you could use *one* column of type [`enum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html) or a small look-up table and a foreign key referencing it. (Ruled out in question update.)

Comment: FYI I came across this question because it was tagged as SQL Server. If the OP is not using SQL Server, then the tag should be removed.

Comment: @Aaron I am interested in both the general answers and in the db specific ones, even though I am using postgres i am interested in knowing how other db's deal with issue, this is why I tagged the question with ms-sql and postgres. I found your blog post useful.

Comment: @ams that's great but I didn't post an answer. :-)

Comment: @Aaron you posted a link to your blog and I found that useful.

Comment: Great answer. I would just add that an advantage is being able to add/remove/change roles without needing a database migration

Answer (score 10):

Disadvantages: Hard to write data, hard to read data, hard to debug, but especially: slow queries because the database cannot use indexes on a query like this.

Advantages, you save a few bytes. Compared to a BIT field, you may save a few MB on a million records table.. hardly worth it. :)

Answer (score 5):

There is at least one huge disadvantage here...

**These conditions are non-SARGable!**

This is a big one and for me would be a dealbreaker.  The bitwise evaluations you need to perform are (to my knowledge) not indexable in any database - the engine needs to check every row to perform the evaluation, which means terrible performance.

Comment: Absolutely. When you have to start adding additional query logic just to use your indexes, you need to question the approach. I blogged about this: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/dry-principle

Comment: @Aaron trick you use in your blog post to get SQL server to do a range scan works on postgres too.

Comment: Apparently it is possible to create partial indexes for bitwise operations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226217/bitwise-operations-in-postgres

Comment: I'm not sure this is necessarily true https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648449/1507124

Answer (score 2):

Adding to previous answers for SQL Server's implementation, you wouldn't save any space by having a single bitfield integer vs a pile of `BIT NOT NULL` columns:

> The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of **bit** columns. If there are 8 or less **bit** columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 **bit** columns, the columns are stored as 2 bytes, and so on.
>
> [bit at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

As JNK mentioned, partial comparisons on a bitfield integer would not be SARGable, so an index on a bitfield integer would be useless unless comparing the entire value at once.

On-disk indexes on SQL Server are based on sorting, so to get to the rows that have any particular bit set in isolation would require a separate index for each bit column. One way to save space if you are only looking for 1s is to make them filtered columns that only store the 1 values (zero values will not have an index entry at all).

```
CREATE TABLE news(
    pkey          INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title         VARCHAR(256),
    company_fk    INTEGER REFERENCES compaines(pkey), -- updated since asking the question
    body          VARCHAR(512),
    public_role BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    restricted_role BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    confidential_role BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    secret_role BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ByPublicRole ON news(public_role, pkey) WHERE public_role=1;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ByRestrictedRole ON news(restricted_role, pkey) WHERE restricted_role=1;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ByConfidentialRole ON news(confidential_role, pkey) WHERE confidential_role=1;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX BySecretRole ON news(secret_role, pkey) WHERE secret_role=1;

select * from news WHERE company_fk=2 AND restricted_role=1 OR confidential_role=1; 
select * from news WHERE company_fk=2 AND restricted_role=1 AND confidential_role=1;
```

Both of those queries produce a nice plan with the random test data I produced:
[image: bit plans]

As always, indexes should be based on actual query usage and balanced against maintenance cost.