# Database performance for filter by integer or boolean?

Tags: java, sql, dao

I will be having a database table with a few million entries, eg products of an online shop.
If one is out of stock, I want to mark it somehow, and I want to exclude it from any `findAll()` sql fetches.

Therefore I though one of the following options:

- each product already has an integer count of availability. I anyhow have to set that = 0. `select * from products where availcount > 0`
- or I could introduce a `boolean available = 'true'` field that I set to false if out of stock, and the query would then be `...where available = 'true'`

Question: will this make any difference? Are there reasons one of these options should be preferred?

Comment: which database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with the stock levels (`int availcount`). Bit fields are typically very [difficult to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270461/any-disadvantages-to-bit-flags-in-database-columns), unless there is a massive skew in the data such that there are of the order of 1% or less products out of stock (and since you will likely be searching for in-stock products only, any index on the flag will be unused).

Since it seems you already store the actual stock level in any event, not storing `available` in stock indicator will save you headaches on trying to keep the two columns in synch.

Finally, many RDBMS's allow you to add COMPUTED columns (or failing which, add the `available` indicator to a VIEW), which will allow you the logical derivation of `available` indicator from the actual `availcount`, without any storage overhead.

**Edit**

- As per the comments below, note that an index on `availcount` (for queries `WHERE availcount = 0` and `availcount > 0`) will be equally un-[SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) as an index on a bit field, although an index may not be needed if the products are generally searched by other criteria.
- In addition to deriving `is available in stock ?` in the database, this determination can also be taken in code, e.g. an additional `bool isAvailable() { return availcount > 0 ;}` method on your entity class.

Comment: while it is true, that an index on a boolean field isn't typically very efficient, its (in)efficiency is identical to that of an `int` column index, used to back queries like `where count > 0`

Comment: Yes, indeed. There will at least be some SARGability on narrow `availcount` ranges (e.g. where availcount between 100 and 120) if a decision was made to index `availcount`. From what the OP is saying (online shop), it sounds like the table in question will be accessed via other primary predicates (recent products, products by category, product by manufacturer, etc), so it is moot whether the stock level index is required at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the availcount column anyway, there is no reason to add a new one, your `availcount > 0` will do. 
If you do not need the count for other reasons, and are just trying to decide between having a count or a boolean, consider how hard it is going to be to update that column rather than filtering.

If you only have a boolean, you'll only need to touch when the product goes out of stock (or comes back in). Having a count is more complex: you'd need to update it every time a sale is made or the item is restocked. This is more complicated, has possible performance implications, and a bunch or corner cases to care about. So, unless you need the count for other purposes, it's, probably, a better idea to stick with the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I think the two options would be equally efficient on `SELECT` as long as there's an index in the column in question.

Indexing `availcount` will have a small penalty on any update of this column (and I guess this column will be updated often). On the other hand, having an `available` column will add redundancy to your database (i.e. it will not be normalized) which you may want to avoid.